# Loop through JSON Cell In SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and I have a table which contains and `Id` and `Json` column.

The JSON looks something like:

```
{
    "data_set": "dbo.[TestData]",
    "model": "testModel",
    "time": "20210226-100404",

    "model_params": {
      "epochs": 900,
      "learning_rate": 0.001,
      "net": "Sequential"
    },
    "train_results": {
      "mse_loss": 234.24234234,
      "r2": 0.43242349,
      "std": 6.145094234322578,
    },
    "validation_results": {
      "mse_loss": 6.674324971,
      "r2": 0.324242213,
      "std": 2.3242346,
    }
  }
```

Now that first JSON value `data_set` I want to loop through all rows and look specifically at that `data_set` value and delete rows depending on a where statement i.e. something along the lines of

```
DELETE FROM dbo.TableOfJson
WHERE NOT (Data_set = '17' or Data_set = '18')
```

So if it see's that example Json which has a `data_set` value of `"dbo.[TestData]"` it will remove it however I am completely fresh to this idea of looping through a cell of json data and would appreciate some guidance.

I don't know if i am looking at something along the right lines but possibly starting something like

```
DECLARE @jsonToDelete NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @jsonToDelete = [Json]
```

Comment: use openjson  to parse json to columns you can read
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Use openJson() to return data as a table which you can then join to.

Comment: I am trying but i am getting an invalid column name when i try to write `DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = [Json] `

Comment: If you need to build a `WHERE` caluse using the value of a specific key in the JSON object, this is an option: `DELETE FROM dbo.TableOfJson
WHERE NOT (JSON_VALUE(Json, '$.Data_set') = '17')`

Comment: @Zhorov That did exactly the trick I needed..if you made this an answer i can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you simply need to get the `"$.data_set"` part of the stored JSON using `JSON_VALUE()` and build the appropriate `WHERE` clause:

```
DELETE TableOfJson
WHERE JSON_VALUE(Json, '$.data_set') NOT IN ('17', '18')
```